# Visual studio -> publish to local folder (remote iis) and queuing requests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, publishing

I'm using visual studio 2019 and I have a question about IIS and queuing request.

When I publish .net 4.6.2 c# API to a "local folder", which is looking like \Servername\c$\inetpub\myapp
Is IIS queuing pending request to process them later?

I've been googling for a while and I did not find a response. (Not even close to be honest!)

Any help will be appreciate, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean exactly. When you publish like that you're just copying the executable code to a folder. That's not directly related to IIS. If you want to serve that application from IIS you need to set up a site / virtual directory in IIS which points to that folder.

Comment: Well, I understand what you mean. So its safe to says that IIS will be "offline" for a few second. According to the time it take to perform the publish.

From what I've seen on our environment, I was sure that IIS did some special things even if its just a "copy paste" of the executable code. I was wrong then!

Comment: No it doesn't really do anything particularly special.

Answer (score 0):

As ADyson said:

> When you publish like that you're just copying the executable code to
> a folder. That's not directly related to IIS. If you want to serve
> that application from IIS you need to set up a site / virtual
> directory in IIS which points to that

Therefore : IIS will be "offline" for a few second. According to the time it take to perform the publish